# How do I sum (up to ~1000) duplicated columns in a short fast way to fix pandas merge function that leads to column renamed _x, _y

Tags: python, csv, merge, duplicates

I am trying to write a function that will merge column names that are found in more than one data frame (csv's). I know how to do it for individual titles, but if I have a dataframe with 1000 columns of which 500 are duplicated with the _x, _y suffix how do i Do that. 
I want to merge two  or more csv files that are the same versions with slightly altered information. However, when I run the code below it doesn't add the duplicated columns. it just overrides it. How do I fix this so that I always sum my columns, and then drop the suffixes? without doing each column 1 by 1.

DataFrame 1

```
sample_name TITLE        Sex    Gender  Ethnicity   Identity 
Cody        Chicken Pox             
Claudia     Chicken Pox             
Alex        Chicken Pox             
Steven      Chicken Pox             
Mom         Chicken Pox             
Dad
```

DataFrame 2

```
sample_name TITLE       Geo_Loc DESCRIPTION Sex Gender  Ethnicity   Identity 
Dad        Chicken Pox  Earth   people       1    1        1          1
Me         Chicken Pox  Earth   people       1    1        1          1
Roger      Chicken Pox  Earth   people       1    1        1          1
Ben        Chicken Pox  Earth   people       1    1        1          1
```

Desired DataFrame

```
Sample_name TITLE       Geo_Loc                 DESCRIPTION             Sex                     Gender                  Ethnicity               Identity 
Cody       Chicken Pox  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable
Claudia    Chicken Pox  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable
Alex       Chicken Pox  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable
Steven     Chicken Pox  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable
Mom        Chicken Pox  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable  Missing:Not Applicable
Dad        Chicken Pox  Earth                    people                 1                       1                       1                      1
Me         Chicken Pox  Earth                    people                 1                       1                       1                     1
Roger      Chicken Pox  Earth                    people                 1                       1                       1                     1
Ben        Chicken Pox  Earth                    people                 1                       1                       1                     1   


#Merging two or more csv files using pandas 
#Duplicate line for more than one csv file 
File_one = panda.read_csv('/Users/c1carpenter/Desktop/Test.txt', sep='\t', header=0, dtype=str)
File_two = panda.read_csv('/Users/c1carpenter/Desktop/Test2.txt', sep='\t', header=0, dtype=str)
Merge_File = panda.merge(File_one, File_two, how='outer', on='sample_name') 

# define our drop function
def sum_duplicated_columns(Merge_File):
# list comprehension of the cols that end with '_y'
to_drop = [x for x in Merge_File if x.endswith('_y')].fillna('').sum(axis=1)
Merge_File.drop(to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

drop_y(Merge_File)
Merge_File

# func to rename '_x' cols
def rename_x(Merge_File):
    for col in Merge_File:
        if col.endswith('_x'):
            Merge_File.rename(columns={col:col.rstrip('_x')}, inplace=True)
rename_x(Merge_File)
Merge_File 

#Replacing Empty cells with Missing:Not Applicable
Merge_File.fillna('Missing:Not Applicable')
```

Comment: Please put your code as an [edit] to your question where you can format it appropriately - it's very hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Could you also demonstrate what columns are present in your merged data... maybe by showing us: `Merge_File.columns` and describing what columns shouldn't be there?

Comment: @JonClements i've edited to clarify